# A set is not an element of itself.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

I know that in modern set theory that for a given set $A$, $A \notin A$, specifically by the axiom of regularity. However, I'm not permitted to use this axiom in my proof. What I am permitted to use are the following:

1. Axiom of Extensionality
2. Emptyset and Pairset Axiom
3. Separation Axiom
4. Powerset Axiom
5. Unionset Axiom
6. Axiom of Infinity

Edit: Thanks to @Git_Gud, I now am aware that a proof of this isn't possible.

The problem that I'm working on is this:

Determine whether the following class is a set or not:

$$\{x | x \text{ is a nonempty set} \}$$

I know this isn't a set by the axiom of regularity. However, I'm not allowed to use this as it appears later on in my textbook. The textbook is, "Notes on Set Theory" 2nd ed., by Moschovakis.

Any tips are appreciated! Thank you! :3

Comment: You can't prove it. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory).

Comment: Haha well that would make sense as to why I couldn't get a contradiction. Thank you! I'll make an edit as to what my homework problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your class is a set, so is the collection of all sets, which I assume you have already shown is not the case. To see this, note that $\emptyset$ exists, and therefore so does $\{\emptyset\}$ and $A\cup\{\emptyset\}$ for any set $A$.

Comment: Ah, thank you! This makes perfect sense. I knew it was something very simple and elegant that would do the trick. :)

Comment: Just a quick question: If we're trying to show that a class IS a set, is it sufficient to show that for at least one of these axioms we get a class that we know for sure is a set? E.g.: Taking the unionset and getting a class that we know to be a set.

Comment: Sure, that is typically how we proceed. The separation axiom is particularly useful in practice.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help, Andres!

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, "*If your class is a set, so is the collection of all sets*". How so? Please can you step through why this is the case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

{x|x is a nonempty set} is a proper class (not a set) because is too large (is the universe minus $\{\emptyset\}$). And, as I know, the axiom of regularity is not required for this.

Details of "is too large":

If $A=\{x|x\ne\emptyset\}=V-\{\emptyset\}$ set then by union axiom $V$ is a set. If $V$ is a set, by powerset axiom $P(V)$ is a set. But $P(V)=V$, impossible by Cantor.

---

Comment: Why is it too large? Showing that is the point of the exercise. What does your last sentence mean?

Comment: The axiom of regularity implies that a set is never an element of itself according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), and as the above set would be an element of itself...

Comment: OK, stupid phrasing. "The axiom of regularity is not required".